# Fixed-precision intersection complains that i need GEOS 3.9 or higher, but PostGIS_GEOS_Version() is 3.9

Tags: postgresql, postgis, geos

Im trying to use the ST_SubDivide with a grid_size, however i get the following error:

`ERROR:  Fixed-precision intersection requires GEOS-3.9 or higher`

But when i run `SELECT PostGIS_GEOS_Version();` it returns:

`3.9.0-CAPI-1.16.2`

Do anyone have a clue as to why it runs into this issue? Source code seems to only check what the version is:
https://postgis.net/docs/doxygen/3.2/da/de7/liblwgeom_8h_ab0aae42ba93f3734ed9469ccb849b9d9.html